# jQuery, Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some javascript code on my webpage that is loading some divs onto the page. I also want to add onmouseenter, and onmouseleave event handlers to each div. I am using jquery to add these handlers, but i get the error:

> "Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function"

My code looks like this, it is in a for loop:

```
var newItem = document.createElement('div');
newItem.innerHTML = results[i];
newItem.setAttribute("id", "resultDiv_" + i.toString());
dropDown.appendChild(newItem);

//Error on next line...
$("resultDiv_" + i.toString()).bind("mouseenter", function() {
    $("resultDiv_" + i.toString()).css({ 'background-color': 'blue' });
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas why i am getting this error, or even what the error means?

Comment: just curious, where did you put this block of code that uses $ (jquery)?

Comment: it is inside a function that fires as a result of a webMethod returning results[]...which is initiated as a result of a keyup event in a textbox... :D

Comment: do you use other other javascripts(framework perhaps), you might as well try using jquery.noconflict

Comment: where would i add jquery.noconflict? i don't quite understand what the documentation is saying

Comment: the problem here might be cause by the $ which is the jQuery's shorthand, there might be another javascript that already used this as variable or function perhaps, to solve this issue you must use another reference for jquery(not $).

Comment: for instance var J = jQuery.noConflict(); you can now use J as  J("resultDiv_" + i.toString()) instead of $.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that jQuery is properly loaded? Could it be a conflict with another javascript library?

Comment: Thanks for the help, turns out i wasn't loading jQuery properly :(

Comment: Speaking about conflicts with other javascript libraries...some addons in Chrome load additional javascript...if you are running Chrome it helps to turn off your addons and try it again.

Comment: remember that users from your web site shouldn't be required to turn off their addons, so you've got to find a fix if you can't get it working without disabling addons

Answer (score 9):

Try replacing all occurrences of `$` with `jQuery`.

Also the selector `$("resultDiv_" + i.toString())` won't likely return any elements. You probably meant: `$("#resultDiv_" + i.toString())`

And finally make sure this code is executed when the DOM is ready i.e. inside:

```
jQuery(function() {
    // Put your code here
});
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, i replaced $ with jQuery, but i still get the error, with 'jQuery' instead of '$' now. 
also added the #

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. However, i don't have any other libraries loaded... why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

```
(function ($) {
    // All your code here
})(jQuery);
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

What about trying this?

```
      var newItem = document.createElement('div');
        newItem.innerHTML = results[i];
        newItem.setAttribute("id", "resultDiv_" + i.toString());
        dropDown.appendChild(newItem);

        //Error on next line...
        $("resultDiv_" + i.toString()).mouseenter( function() {
            $("resultDiv_" + i.toString()).css({ 'background-color': 'blue' });
        });
```

Or make sure that `$("resultDiv_" + i.toString())` is not `null`. Use Firebug to inspect the element.

Answer (score 0):

You might as well try this:

```
  var newItem = jQuery('<div id="' + "resultDiv_" + i.toString() + '">+ results[i] + '</div');
  jQuery(dropDown).append(newItem);
  //Error on next line...
  newItem.mouseenter(function(){
      jQuery(this).css( 'background-color', 'blue');
  });
```

or perhaps jQuery.noConflict will solve this.